# Postgres stopping on Windows

Tags: windows, postgresql, database

I have a Postgres 9.2 running on Windows 7 as a service.
Every day the database seems to stop and sometimes it start to run again alone and sometimes I need to restart the service.
There is no much log information, I dont have a antivirus, firewall installed on this computer. I tried to improve the log information but it didnt helped much.

I could not find the same problem on the internet or here on serverfault.

There is some log information:

2016-09-08 06:25:27 BRT [unknown] LOG:  XX000: could not receive data

```
from client: unrecognized winsock error 10061
2016-09-08 06:25:27 BRT [unknown] LOCATION:  pq_recvbuf, src\backend\libpq\pqcomm.c:831
2016-09-08 06:25:27 BRT [unknown] LOG:  XX000: could not receive data from client: unrecognized winsock error 10061
2016-09-08 06:25:27 BRT [unknown] LOCATION:  pq_recvbuf, src\backend\libpq\pqcomm.c:831
2016-09-08 06:55:39 BRT [unknown] LOG:  XX000: could not receive data from client: unrecognized winsock error 10061
2016-09-08 06:55:39 BRT [unknown] LOCATION:  pq_recvbuf, src\backend\libpq\pqcomm.c:831
2016-09-08 06:55:39 BRT [unknown] LOG:  XX000: could not receive data from client: unrecognized winsock error 10061
2016-09-08 06:55:39 BRT [unknown] LOCATION:  pq_recvbuf, src\backend\libpq\pqcomm.c:831
2016-09-08 07:15:25 BRT [unknown] LOG:  XX000: could not receive data from client: unrecognized winsock error 10061
2016-09-08 07:15:25 BRT [unknown] LOCATION:  pq_recvbuf, src\backend\libpq\pqcomm.c:831
2016-09-08 07:15:25 BRT [unknown] LOG:  XX000: could not receive data from client: unrecognized winsock error 10061
2016-09-08 07:15:25 BRT [unknown] LOCATION:  pq_recvbuf, src\backend\libpq\pqcomm.c:831
2016-09-08 10:59:20 BRT [unknown] LOG:  XX000: could not receive data from client: unrecognized winsock error 10061
2016-09-08 10:59:20 BRT [unknown] LOCATION:  pq_recvbuf, src\backend\libpq\pqcomm.c:831
2016-09-08 10:59:20 BRT [unknown] LOG:  XX000: could not receive data from client: unrecognized winsock error 10061
2016-09-08 10:59:20 BRT [unknown] LOCATION:  pq_recvbuf, src\backend\libpq\pqcomm.c:831
2016-09-08 11:14:55 BRT [unknown] LOG:  XX000: could not receive data from client: unrecognized winsock error 10061
2016-09-08 11:14:55 BRT [unknown] LOCATION:  pq_recvbuf, src\backend\libpq\pqcomm.c:831
2016-09-08 11:14:55 BRT [unknown] LOG:  XX000: could not receive data from client: unrecognized winsock error 10061
2016-09-08 11:14:55 BRT [unknown] LOCATION:  pq_recvbuf, src\backend\libpq\pqcomm.c:831
2016-09-08 11:16:08 BRT [unknown] LOG:  XX000: could not receive data from client: unrecognized winsock error 10061
2016-09-08 11:16:08 BRT [unknown] LOCATION:  pq_recvbuf, src\backend\libpq\pqcomm.c:831
2016-09-08 11:16:08 BRT [unknown] LOG:  XX000: could not receive data from client: unrecognized winsock error 10061
2016-09-08 11:16:08 BRT [unknown] LOCATION:  pq_recvbuf, src\backend\libpq\pqcomm.c:831
```

If I leave PgAdmin III open with the server status windows I get theses messages too.

Any tips?

Thank you

Comment: Running 4 year old DB software on a client OS well past mainstream support it asking for odd problems like this.

Comment: Do you think it worths to update to the last 9.2 or migrate to a new version?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, run production server in a desktop machine it's a bad practice. I recommend you to migrate for a dedicated server with a Server operating system like Windows server, Linux, etc.

About your error<sup>[1]</sup>, looks like you are experiencing a network error:

> **Connection refused.**
>
> No connection could be made because the target computer actively refused it. This usually results from trying to connect to a service that is inactive on the foreign host—that is, one with no server application running.

Take a look here<sup>[2]</sup> for more details.

Consider my suggestion if you already given up to solve your network problems.

Hope it helps.

References:

1. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740668(v=vs.85).aspx
2. https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/9837222c1002240818x6c07547dg445a177163afcf6b@mail.gmail.com